# Nodes - Working on fixing some implementation

Tags: debugging, nodes, implementation

The purpose of the following code is to create a string representation of a node-chain, but the code has a bug in it. You can find the error message below. I am not having the best times with nodes. If you could just give me some guidance I would appreciate it:

```
if node_chain is None:
    result = 'EMPTY'
    return result
else:
    # walk along the chain
    walker = node_chain
    value = node.get_data(walker)
    # print the data
    result = '[ ' + str(value) + ' |'
    while walker is not None:
        walker = node.get_next(walker)
        value = node.get_data(walker)
        # represent the next with an arrow-like figure
        result += ' *-]-->[ '+str(value)+' |'

    # at the end of the chain, use '/'
    result += ' / ]'

return result
```

I am using a node ADT and I have testing. I keep getting errors saying:

```
file "C:/Users/Daniel/Downloads/a5q1_testing.py", line 28, in <module>
result = a5q1.to_string(args_in)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\Downloads\a5q1.py", line 28, in to_string
value = node.get_data(walker)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\Downloads\node.py", line 37, in get_data
assert node is not None, "get_data() called with argument None"
AssertionError: get_data() called with argument None
```

I hope this is not to much information.
Any advice would be appreciated. If you need more context, please let me know.

Comment: `walker = node.get_next(walker)` occurs and value assigned to `walker` is *NOT CHECKED* (ie. that it is "not None") before `value = node.get_data(walker)`, and it is this line that raises the error; since `walker` MUST be None at some point to terminate the loop, it's a logical ordering violation. Perhaps `walker` should be updated at the *end* of the loop, before the next check, and after it has been utilized within the loop body?

Comment: *I am not asking for someone to answer this for me.* - Being that StackOverflow is a Question and Answer site, not a discussion forum, I would say you have come to the wrong place. While hints can be posted as comments, anything that is not specifically addressing your question posted as an *answer* is likely to be deleted. That said, your question title doesn't sound like something that can be answered in one go anyway, which makes it off-topic here.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I reformatted and rephrased your question to adhere to SO standards. As @NightOwl888 noted, this is a Q&A site so all posts have to be in Q&A format. If you are interested in receiving feedback for your (running) code, you might be interested in the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange.